# kdoc link to local file so that link works in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kdoc

In Kotlin doc comments I can link to a website

```kotlin
/**
 * [go to this website](https://www.google.com)
 */
```

I can link to a class

```kotlin
/**
 * [look at this class][SomeClass]
 */
```

But how can I link to a *file* in the repository such that clicking it in Android Studio opens the file?

```kotlin
/**
 * [see our documentation](../ourDocs.md) 
 * [see our documentation](file:/absolute/path/to/ourDocs.md)
 * neither works, makes a link but click does nothing
 */
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out as well